# allow only hindi numerals as input in razor textbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-core

I have to create a razor text box where users should allow to input **only hindi digits** {०,१,२,३,...९}. How can I do that?

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Region, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type="number",@min="0",@max="8" } })
```

Comment: Could you please share your full code to reproduce the issue so that it can be resolve quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer that could help you if what you are looking for is to let the user type hindi character with their QWERTY keyboard.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22794496/16688813